# OpenSSL TimeStampQuery equivalent in PHP

Tags: php, openssl, php-openssl

I'm trying to create a TimeStampQuery (tsq) to use with the [Time-Stamp Protocol](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3161.txt). In order to achieve this, I'm using the following OpenSSL terminal command:

```sh
openssl ts -query -data input_file.xml -no_nonce -sha512 -out request.tsq
```

Can the [OpenSSL PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/book.openssl.php) generate Time-Stamp Queries without the need of an external executable? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a feasible alternative written entirely in PHP: https://github.com/vakata/asn1

It is designed to create and parse [Abstract Syntax Notation One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) data structures, but comes with a specific class for generating Time-Stamp Queries which is really straight-forward to use:

```php
$message = "Hello World";
$tsq = \vakata\asn1\Timestamp::generateRequestFromData($message);
// Send TSQ to an authorized entity
```

The documentation related to the previous method can be found [here](https://github.com/vakata/asn1/blob/master/docs/Timestamp.md#vakataasn1timestampgeneraterequestfromdata).